# Can you tell me which one of these substances are highly or easily flammable?

Tags: organic-chemistry, safety, alcohols

List is next:
ethylene glycol (EG), 
diethylene glycol (DEG), 
triethy-lenglycol (TEG)
basicly liquids from polyol groups,
I know alcohols are flammable but what about polyols? and how easily

Comment: http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/ Look up the safety data sheets for the compounds and see whether they say "flammable".

Comment: they dont have all of them

Comment: They have all the ones you listed. Check your spelling of triethylene glycol. In any case I am fairly sure all of those are rather flammable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The USA [legal definition](https://www.osha.gov/dte/library/flammable_liquids/flammable_liquids.html) per [29 CFR 1910.106](https://www.osha.gov/pls/oshaweb/owadisp.show_document?p_table=STANDARDS&p_id=9752) of "flammable" is:

> Flammable liquid: any liquid having a flash point below 100ºF (37.8ºC)

None of the three substances is flammable by that definition.

The [respective flash points](http://www.dow.com/ethyleneglycol/about/properties.htm) by the Penskey-Martens Closed Cup method are:

Ethylene Glycol: 241ºF (116ºC)

Diethylene Glycol: 310ºF (154ºC)

Triethylene Glycol: 350ºF (177ºC)

---

Update: Now the rule has been changed to:

> Flammable liquid means any liquid having a flashpoint at or below 199.4 °F (93 °C)

Comment: How can I find flash point of these substances?

Comment: @SSimon I added flash points and reference to answer

Comment: thank you very much @DavePhD do you know if sparkling wire ( electrical current) above liquid can cause substance to flame? ( Current spark is around 500 C)

Comment: @SSimon if the temperature of the liquid is below the flash point, a hot spark above the liquid will not ignite the liquid or its vapor.

Comment: @DavePhD Is this hazard classification still valid in the US since the new OSHA Hazard Communication Standard (HCS) has adopted the Globally Harmonized System of Classification and Labeling of Chemicals (GHS)?

Comment: @Loong now the definition has been changed to "Flammable liquid means any liquid having a flashpoint at or below 199.4 °F (93 °C)" http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp=1&SID=6a2be1c9d6b4f12de646eba495c8ee3f&ty=HTML&h=L&mc=true&n=pt29.5.1910&r=PART#se29.5.1910_1106

Comment: @DavePhD do you remember about you question on academia that you asked about some author that stole your idea from Sceptics SE?

Comment: @SSimon yes, but he agreed to mention Skeptics in the paper, so everything is ok

Comment: @DavePhD https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4354/i-need-permission-to-reuse-photo-from-user-porphyrin-answer-on-question-about?noredirect=1#comment7822_4354 can you help me with this, since you are most into it?